# Script to refresh at 1 minute after each solid hour

Tags: javascript

This is my script, but I sure could use some help cleaning it up.  Instead of the redundancies on waiting for each our to make the call.  there has got to be an easier way. (I am not a programmer, just a guy wanting to get

some little page to refresh once an hour at exactly one minute past the current hour

```
'''

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }

then.setHours(hours);    
  then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}

refreshAt(00,01,0);
refreshAt(01,01,0);
refreshAt(02,01,0);
refreshAt(03,01,0);
refreshAt(04,01,0);
refreshAt(05,01,0);
refreshAt(06,01,0);
refreshAt(07,01,0);
refreshAt(08,01,0);
refreshAt(09,01,0);
refreshAt(10,01,0);
refreshAt(11,01,0);
refreshAt(12,01,0);
refreshAt(13,01,0);
refreshAt(14,01,0);
refreshAt(15,01,0);
refreshAt(16,01,0);
refreshAt(17,01,0);
refreshAt(18,01,0);
refreshAt(19,01,0);
refreshAt(20,01,0);
refreshAt(21,01,0);
refreshAt(22,01,0);
refreshAt(23,01,0);

</SCRIPT>
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass hours to the function, just calculate it

```
function refreshAt(minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();
    hours = now.getHours() + (now.getMinutes() ? 1 : 0);
    if (now.getHours() > hours ||
        (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }

    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }, timeout);
}

refreshAt(1, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I see the trees again in my forest!!